# Looping over list in reverse, removing elements as we go

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare

I'm comparing two lists. **A** & **B**. *Hi **A**, how you doin'? I'm okay, **B***. If item **A** appears in list **B** it should be removed from list **A**. The comparisons are lists of RGB colours.

Only it's out of range and I don't know why as I'm looping over the list in reverse.

```
data = [
[224,  96,  96],
[128, 32, 192], # match
[192, 32, 160], # match
]

myColours = [
[207, 30, 30],
[207,159, 30],
[ 79,207, 30],
[ 32, 64, 192],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

for x in list(range(len(data)-1, -1, -1)):
  for y in range(0, len(myColours)):
    if myColours[y] == data[x]:
      print (data[x])
      data.remove(data[x]) # list index out of range
```

The list *data* should end up as

```
data = [
[224,  96,  96]
]
```

Data will be generated by code, myColours by hand. Their order is not important, just the values.

Comment: You shouldn't remove elements from the same list you are operating on, Consider making another array, use list comphrensions, or make a copy of the original array

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
data = [
[224,  96,  96],
[128, 32, 192], # match
[192, 32, 160], # match
]

myColours = [
[207, 30, 30],
[207,159, 30],
[ 79,207, 30],
[ 32, 64, 192],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

data = [item for item in data if item not in myColours]

#to iterate backwards:
#data = [item for item in reversed(data) if item not in myColours]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code can be:

```
data = [
[224,  96,  96],
[128, 32, 192], 
[192, 32, 160], 
]

myColours = [
[207, 30, 30],
[207,159, 30],
[ 79,207, 30],
[ 32, 64, 192],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

l=len(myColours)

for i in range(0,l):
    for x in data:
        if x in myColours:
            data.remove(x)
            
print(data)
```

After running the code I wrote, the output is coming as:

```
[[224, 96, 96]]
```

Answer (score 1):

there is two ways to solve your problem:

first:

```
data = [
[224, 96, 96],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

myColours = [
[207, 30, 30],
[207, 159, 30],
[79, 207, 30],
[32, 64, 192],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

a = 0
x = len(data)
while a < len(data):
    for i in myColours:
        if data[a] == i:
            del(data[a])
            a = 0
            break
    if a < len(data):
        a += 1
 print(data)
```

second:

```
data = [
[224, 96, 96],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

myColours = [
[207, 30, 30],
[207, 159, 30],
[79, 207, 30],
[32, 64, 192],
[128, 32, 192],
[192, 32, 160],
]

data2 = data.copy()

x = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    for i2 in myColours:
        if data[i] == i2:
            del(data2[i-x])
            x += 1
            break
print(data2)
```

and also there is a way with branches but it's not perfect way.